# Data Connector for Salesforce (GSheets) - Errors

Tags: google-apps

Our company uses Salesforce Connector (Data Connector for Salesforce) add-on on Google Sheets, to import reports from our Salesforce platform.

Recently, as per company policy we have been enforcing users to use Google SSO to loging to SF (Session Security Level Required at Login = High Assurance).

However, some users have reported some issues with reports in GSheets connected to SF via this add-on; reports retrieved on demand seem to work ok, but the ones that are scheduled keep running into this error:

[image]

This problem stops happening when the setting (Session Security Level Required at Login) is reversed.

Any ideas on what this might be happening?

Thanks in advance!
eclf

Answer (score 0):

I kept having these types of bugs with the Data Connector and was annoyed Google doesn't offer any support for it. Also sometimes just spontaneously failed refreshes with no logged fail on the auto-execution log so we would miss it and report bad data to our sales team. I eventually switched to Coefficient's add-on for Sheets and haven't looked back since.